# .NET Core 2.0 Webpage keeping data on cache

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-2.0, windows-server-2012

I'm having problems with caching an ASP CORE 2.0 application, published in IIS, it's as if the server was holding a cache of pages. Here are two examples:

- if I access the login page for the first time, the main page is with the data of the last logged-in user, but when I press F5, it is redirected to the login page;
- when you perform some tasks in the application, and navigate to Home, the data displayed in the dashboard is not updated and you must press F5 to refresh the page.

This occurs ONLY on the production server. In debugging, on Visual Studio, this does not occur, the application works perfectly.

- Windows Server 2012
- IIS 6
- ASP CORE 2.0

Comment: Post your Startup.cs

Comment: I found a solution, adding the following attribute in my Index action:

[ResponseCache(Duration =0, NoStore =false, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None )]